# Displaying huge, scrollable graphics in Flex, part 2: BitmapData into an Image?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Clox answered [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210147/displaying-huge-scrollable-images-in-image) of how to display huge graphics (e.g. greater than 8191 pixels).

I have the code to copy parts of a huge loaded BitmapData to a target BitmapData that is just the size that I can display.

I think I have set the scroll bars of an enclosing Canvas to show the size of the larger image and allow the user to scroll.

Now I need to put the selected pixels on the screen. When I try to add a Bitmap component as a child of the Canvas, it get an error because Bitmap is not a UIComponent.

*What's the best way to put the target BitmapData into an Image component?*

*How else can I get the subset of pixels on the screen?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display a [BitmapData](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html) object use the [Bitmap](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Bitmap.html) class. Then you can set the bitmap as the source of an image.

```
var imageBmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(myBitmapData);
var displayImage:Image = new Image();
displayImage.source = imageBmp;
myCanvas.addChild(displayImage);
```

You could also draw the pixels of your bitmap data directly onto the [Graphics](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/Graphics.html) object of the Canvas using [beginBitmapFill](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/Graphics.html#beginBitmapFill%28%29).

```
var g:Graphics = myCanvas.graphics;
g.beginBitmapFill(myBitmapData);
g.drawRect(0, 0, myBitmapData.width, myBitmapData.height);
```